# Typescript : Add the removed drop down value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to typescript. I have to remove a drop down option, for which I did

```
this.dropDownFilter = values => values.filter(option => option.value !== 'Others')
```

Now how to I add back the removed option, on drop down change? I tried

```
this.dropDownFilter = values => [
new DropDownOptions('Others', '1')
]
```

But this is removing other options and just showing 'Others' in drop down. Please guide me how to add back the removed option. Thanks

Comment: what was called in your `dropDownFilter`? The array you put in the arguments(values), just push the data in this. Revel the more code and solution would be found faster.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to push the new value to your array like this:

```
this.dropDownFilter.push(new DropDownOptions('Others', '1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for adding removed value. As values are array, if you assign directly - it will remove all other options and keep the last one which you just assigned. So you need to push a value to the array.

```
this.dropDownFilter = values => values.push(new DropDownOptions('Others', '1'))
```